# how to compare rows from 2 sheets and then copy the different rows to another sheet vba

Tags: excel, vba

i have 2 sheets:

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2:

[image]

I'm running a comparison of the rows in sheet 1 and sheet 2 and excluding the first column of both. I found the following code online but it is returning that there are no rows that are not matching. however, in sheet 2, there is an additional row for c that has a value of $8.00 that is not found in sheet one. that is the one that i would expect to copy into sheet 3.

when i run this code, it is saying that there are no differences between the sheets but there is definitely an additional row in sheet 2 that is not found in sheet 1, excluding the first column of dates.

Can anyone please assist?

```
Sub Compare()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
    ' compare two different worksheets in the active workbook
    CompareWorksheets Worksheets("Sheet1"), Worksheets("Sheet2")
End Sub

Sub CompareWorksheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
    Dim dupRow As Boolean
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer, m As Integer
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, lc1 As Integer, lc2 As Integer, lr3 As Long
    Dim maxR As Long, maxC As Integer, cf1 As String, cf2 As String
    Dim dupCount As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Creating the report..."
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    With ws1.UsedRange
        lr1 = .Rows.Count
        lc1 = .Columns.Count
    End With
    With ws2.UsedRange
        lr2 = .Rows.Count
        lc2 = .Columns.Count
    End With
    maxR = lr1
    maxC = lc1
    If maxR < lr2 Then maxR = lr2
    If maxC < lc2 Then maxC = lc2
    DiffCount = 0
    lr3 = 1
    For i = 1 To lr1
        dupRow = True
        Application.StatusBar = "Comparing worksheets " & Format(i / maxR, "0 %") & "..."
        For r = 1 To lr2
            For c = 2 To maxC
                ws1.Select
                cf1 = ""
                cf2 = ""
                On Error Resume Next
                cf1 = ws1.Cells(i, c).FormulaLocal
                cf2 = ws2.Cells(r, c).FormulaLocal
                On Error GoTo 0
                If cf1 <> cf2 Then
                    dupRow = False
                    Exit For
                Else
                    dupRow = True
                End If
            Next c
            If dupRow Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
        If Not dupRow Then
            dupCount = dupCount + 1
            ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Cells(i, maxC)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lr3, 1), Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lr3, maxC)).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial
            lr3 = lr3 + 1
            ws1.Select
            For t = 1 To maxC
                ws1.Cells(i, t).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
                ws1.Cells(i, t).Select
                Selection.Font.Bold = True
            Next t
        End If
    Next i
    Application.StatusBar = "Formatting the report..."
    'Columns("A:IV").ColumnWidth = 10
    m = dupCount
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox m & " Rows contain different values!", vbInformation, _
           "Compare " & ws1.Name & " with " & ws2.Name


     End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only checking if any rows in Sheet1, is duplicated in Sheet2.  You are not checking the other way (Sheet2 to Sheet1).  In your example, if you pass Sheet2 as the first parameter, you would get the correct result.

```
CompareWorksheets Worksheets("Sheet2"), Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

But this may not work on another set where you have some unique rows in both Sheet1 as well as Sheet2.  For that, you can use your logic, but remember to store the row numbers in Sheet2, that are duplicated.  At the end, also include in Sheet3 the rows that were not marked as duplicates.